# Combining JQuery and Ajax Submission with ASP.NET fails in non trivial cases

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

There is a example: [Combining JQuery Form Validation and Ajax Submission with ASP.NET by Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/21/combining-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submission-with-asp.net.aspx)
I just want to use AjaxSubmission to asp.net forms from there.
So, it works in simple cases when input id is like "submitButton".

```
<input type="hidden" name="<%= submitButton.ClientID %>" 
value="Send Comment" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitButton" 
OnClick="OnFormSubmit" Text="Send Comment" />
```

And when I'm putting button in any container and id becomes smth like: "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_train1" it fails... Event doesn't fire

The only difference I found: doPostback sends ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24submitButton

Why he replaces underscores with %24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just forgot about $ simbols in names.